# Holomorphic map of closed unit disc on itself

Tags: complex-analysis

How to proof , that every holomorphic map of closed unit disc on itself has got some fixed point , so that $f(z_0)=z_0$?

Comment: It’s called the Brouwer fixed point theorem and the map only needs to be continuous.

Comment: So I want to prove it using argument principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will write $\mathbb{B}$ for the open unitary disk, and $\partial\mathbb{B}$ for its boundary

First of all, let us note that the theorem is equivalent to the assertion that the function $f(z)-z$ has at least one zero on $\mathbb{B}\cup\partial\mathbb{B}$. We will prove this assertion.

If the function $f(z)-z$ has a zero on $\partial\mathbb{B}$ the theorem is  proved, so let us suppose it is non zero on $\partial\mathbb{B}$. From this assumption and the fact that $|f(z)|\le 1$, we have, on $\partial \mathbb{B}$

$$|f(z)-z-(-z)|=|f(z)|\le 1<\\
<|f(z)-z|+1=|f(z)-z|+|-z|\\
|f(z)-z-(-z)|<|f(z)-z|+|-z|$$

From a slightly stronger form of  [Rouche theorem](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) (which follows from the argument principle, as proven in the Wikipedia page linked) applied to $f(z)-z$ and $-z$ it follows that $f(z)-z$ and $-z$ have the same number of zeros inside the unitary disk, i.e. one, and the assertion is proved.

**Note:**
As Charlie Frohman mentioned in the comments, this theorem is true under weaker conditions, namely that the function is continuous, and in that form is known as [Brouwer fixed point theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: I see that, thank you!